# Can't make variable global

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, global-variables

OK, I'm not sure whether I'm missing something very basic or if I've simply been a bit confused somewhere between CoffeeScript and JavaScript, but here you are:

I have an ultra simple CoffeeScript:

```
myObject = {

    init: ()->
        console.log("Initialized");
}

(exports ? this).myObject = myObject;
```

Which compiles to:

```
(function() {
  var myObject;

  myObject = {
    init: function() {
      console.log("Initialized");
    }
  };

  (typeof exports !== "undefined" && exports !== null ? exports : this).myObject = myObject;

}).call(this);
```

---

However, when I execute the above code (`eval`'d), the `myObject` instance is nowhere to be found. I mean shouldn't it be available as `window.myObject` or `myObject` (globally)?

What am I missing here?

Comment: What scope are you `eval`ing your code in? Are you `eval`ing this in strict mode?

Comment: Maybe you are not executing the code in global scope?

Comment: @FelixKling Oh my god! Spot on. How is it possible that I have missed that?! Thanks a lot mate! :-)